# Rotate a marker in MapBox SDK for Android

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using [Mapbox Android SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk), I'm going to show a marker on map which is a car location and the marker drawable is a car from top view (head to north) [just like uber app](https://lh6.ggpht.com/CSJNAqePgrCCsP4RIPZmAB2RKPv4h6EzfzEQc20RVlSLyNygIAYOxEpWiVm6RKzD_9s=h900-rw).
My main question is how can i rotate the car marker to show the bearing ?
!

```
    Icon vehicleMarkerIcon = new Icon(vehicleMarkerIconDrawable);
    vehicleMarker.setIcon(vehicleMarkerIcon);
    mapBoxView.addMarker(vehicleMarker);
```

Comment: The easy way is to rotate your bitmap and then set it as marker icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue and solved it with help of Mapbox support team. Refer my answer in the following link 
[Link to adding and rotating marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517370/rotate-and-change-position-for-markers-in-latest-mapbox-sdk-6-7/54124090#54124090)